# How to speed this process up?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning, numerical-integration

```
Clear[Hmp$, "*Hmp*", m, n, p, Nmax, "ψ*"]
Nmax = 10.; (*want 80*)
Hmp = Table[0, {p, Nmax}, {m, Nmax}];

Chop[ReplacePart[Hmp, {m_, p_} :> (p^2 π^2)/2 KroneckerDelta[m, p] + 
  2 Integrate[Sin[m π χ] Sin[p π χ] V[χ], {χ, 0, 1}]]]
```

Comment: Is `V` a defined function?

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `ReplacePart` and not just `Table` or `Array`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: `Chop` has no effect on non-approximate results. I'll venture your use implies you don't need exact/symbolic results. If so, something like `hmp = Table[(p^2 \[Pi]^2)/2 KroneckerDelta[m, p] + 
   2 NIntegrate[
     Sin[m \[Pi] \[Chi]] Sin[p \[Pi] \[Chi]] v[\[Chi]], {\[Chi], 0, 
      1}, Method -> "DoubleExponential"], {m, nmax}, {p, nmax}]` should be much faster. Depends on what *V* is, as noted you've not supplied sufficient information. Also, bad idea in general to use uppercase initials on user-defined symbols/functions/etc.

Answer (score 6):

By taking advantage of the trigonometric identity,

```
2 Sin[m π χ] Sin[p π χ] == Cos[(m - p) π χ] - Cos[(m + p) π χ]
```

the number of integrals to be performed can be reduced from `Nmax^2` to `2*Nmax+1`, as savings of nearly a factor of `40` for `Nmax = 80`.

```
Nmax = 80;
dct = Table[Integrate[Cos[i π χ] V[χ], {χ, 0, 1}], {i, 0, 2 Nmax}];
Hmp = Table[(p^2 π^2)/2 KroneckerDelta[m, p] + 
        dct[[Abs[m - p] + 1]] - dct[[m + p + 1]], {p, Nmax}, {m, Nmax}]
```

Additionally, if `V[χ]` is known at the time that dct is calculated, then

```
dct = FourierCosSeries[V[χ], χ, 2 Nmax, FourierParameters -> {1, π}]
```

can be used instead.